# How to perform some Action on imageview clicked?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm working on a photo Collage application. I want to perform an action on image view so any one can help me to solve my problem.  when i pick image from photo library and shown  on image view  after when double click on image view i want to push or present a new view  to crop this image .....so anyone tell me what i do to solve my problem...

Comment: As the answers below suggest, if ther is no pressing reason to use `UIImageView` you'd be much better of using custom `UIButton`

Answer (score 3):

Use a UIButton of type custom and put an image inside it. And you are done.

Comment: i also check this one but when i clicked second time on button it again perform same action so how to solve this problem

Comment: @kuldeepsingh disable the button once it is clicked... button.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

Answer (score 2):

Add the Gesture for ImageView

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *sg=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(HandleEvent)];
    sg.numberOfTapsRequired=2;
    [BottomBar addGestureRecognizer:sg];
    [sg release];
```

and do your task here:

```
-(void)HandleEvent
{

// your task
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use a UIButton instead of an UIImageView. You can set its style to custom and then asign it an image. UIButton provides all the methods for double tap already built in.

Comment: In many cases this the better solution. It pointed me in the right direction! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make a button, and clear its color. On the back of button, put your image view, so that your imageview seems to be visible and the button doesn't. Now attach event to the button.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using UIImageView, make sure you use `setUserInteractionEnabled:YES`. Then you need to check your touches in touchesBegan, ended, (canceled).

Answer (score 0):

You are set on using UIImageView, you will have to subclass UIImageView and override the touch methods you want to intercept. For example:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   // Call super to make sure you don't lose any functionality
   [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

   // Perform the actions you want to perform with the tap.
}
```

Using UIButtons as replacements for your UIImageViews is a great idea you can just drag a connection from each button to an outlet in your view controller and handle the action. You can set the background image on the buttons as you are doing currently with the UIImageViews. Set your button type to custom and you'll be good to g

Answer (score 0):

If you are using UIImageView class ,first set setUserInteractionEnabled:YES . Then set UITapGestureRecognizer event to image view.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
 CGPoint locationPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint viewPoint = [imageView convertPoint:locationPoint fromView:self.view];
    if ([imageView pointInside:viewPoint withEvent:event]) {
       //do something
    }
}
```